# AngularJs - Broadcast event to single controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, typescript

I have a page where there are a list of Leads who each can have certain actions. Each action is a form so the same form can be displayed multiple times on the same page.

Each form has it's own scope and it;s own instance of the controller. When the form is submitted, I call a service to do the ajax operation and upon completion I broadcast a message, and in the controller I listen to the message. The problem is because each instance of the form has its own instance of the controller, the even listener is fired for each form. How can I only call this for the active controller? Here is some sampel code:

The service:

```
/**
    * Delegate downline submit
    */
    delegatedDownlineSubmit(delegateDownLineModel: IDelegateDownLineModel) {
        this.PostJson('/api/Lead/DelegateDownLine', delegateDownLineModel)
            .success(function (response: IAjaxResponse) {
                if (response !== null) {
                    LeadServices.rootScope.$broadcast('LeadService.DelegatedDownlineSubmitted', response);
                }
            });
    }
```

Controller - called once for each instance of form:

```
delegateDownLineFormScope.$on('LeadService.DelegatedDownlineSubmitted', function (event: ng.IAngularEvent, ajaxResponse: IAjaxResponse) {
            //Do stuff
        });
```

I have also tried calling the broadcast only on the scope:

```
LeadServices.rootScope.BroadcastToElement('#Lead_123 form[name=DelegateDownLineForm]', 'LeadService.DelegatedDownlineSubmitted', response);

    /**
     * Broadcast a message to another element on the page
     */
    scope.BroadcastToElement = function (selector: any, message: string, ...args: any[]) {
        var broadcastArgs = [message];
        if (args) {
            broadcastArgs = broadcastArgs.concat(args);
        }

        return angular.element(selector).scope().$broadcast.apply(this, broadcastArgs);
    };
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best solution...and I'll take any better answer, but for now I've fixed it by passing the id of the current scope as an extra parameter, e.g.

leadService.delegatedDownlineSubmit(delegateDownLineFormScope.DelegateDownLineModel, delegateDownLineFormScope.$id);

And then broadcasting using that extra paramter:

LeadServices.rootScope.$broadcast('LeadService.DelegatedDownlineSubmitted' + scopeId, response);

And finally:

delegateDownLineFormScope.$on('LeadService.DelegatedDownlineSubmitted' + delegateDownLineFormScope.$id etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Based on

> Each form has it's own scope and it;s own instance of the controller.

and

> How can I only call this for the active controller

## Solution

How do you determine the `active controller`? If its something like `active = true` just use that in the even listener:

```
delegateDownLineFormScope.$on('LeadService.DelegatedDownlineSubmitted',  (event: ng.IAngularEvent, ajaxResponse: IAjaxResponse)  => {
            if(this.active){
            //Do stuff
            }
        });
```

Also note I am using an arrow (`=>`) function.